# How do I put iOS application in background mode, with audio option set?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, background, accelerometer

So my application for iphone4 reads data from the accelerometer and sends it to another application via tcp sockets. I need my app to work in background mode, so what I did was:

- I put an mp3 file in the application's **Documents folder**
- I used **AVAudioPlayer** library to play the file in a loop. *It works.*
- I edited **Info.plist** and added option "required background
  modes" with "audio" on.

Still, the scheduler suspends the application whenever I press the iphone's home button. Is there anything I missed?

I read apple's documentation, but I didn't find a solution. A few thoughts on this:

- do I have to edit appDelegate.m?
- is it because I use AVAudioPlayer instead of the **iPod**?
- is it because I play an audio file from the application documents
  folder?
- I read about one person changing iOS Development Target from 4.0 to
  3.2.1, but that didn't work for me.

And finally, say I get this to work, **would the application still be getting data from the accelerometer?**

*On a side note, I don't want to submit the application to the App Store.*

Comment: Are you planning on submitting this to the App Store? My gut tells me that it would be rejected for misusing the audio background mode, as its main purpose is not to play audio at all.

Comment: What @Shaggy said.  Also, I doubt the application would still be receiving accelerometer data just because that has no use to something playing audio.  Why do you need the accelerometer to be gathering data in the background to begin with?

Comment: The application, right now, is only for demonstration purposes. I'm not going to submit it to the App Store.

Comment: I need to receive data from the accelerometer because my application does its own computations with it and then sends the result to this other app that must be in the foreground (among other stuff, it displays what the user has to see).I don't think I can bundle the two together as this second app isn't technically an iPhone app... just something on top of a browser.

Answer (score 4):

No, you will not receive accelerometer notifications in background mode. As far as I know, it is not possible. Check [Executing Code in Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

If you read the docs carefully, you will know that the whole background code model is based on responding to specific events (`location` and `voip` modes).

As for the `audio` mode here is an extract from Apple:

> Your application should limit itself to doing only the work necessary
>   to provide data for playback while in the background. For example, a
>   streaming audio application would download any new data from its
>   server and push the current audio samples out for playback. You should
>   not perform any extraneous tasks that are unrelated to playing the
>   content.

Comment: Well, I thought was only if I wanted to have my app published on the App Store, right?  I only need to run it on my iphone, so I could bypass that requirement, and as long as it plays music, the whole application should be running, even though in the background. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the app will be suspended as soon as your audio playback is stopped. Have you set the audio session category?

Comment: Nope, I just do this: `AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myFileUrl] error:NULL];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; // infinite loops
    [audioPlayer play];`
The app does play the song, but the scheduler just doesn't seem to care. I skimmed through [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW3) but does that apply to my case?     Thanks for helping!

Comment: Sure it applies. Check the last bit of source code in this tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/

Comment: Neat! So that tells the system that something is being played and that the system should act accordingly, huh? I can't test it right now, but I will certainly try it.  Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, so I added those two lines of code and the application, or at least the music, keeps running. Too bad I don't get any data from the accelerometer when the application is in the background. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you have solved your issue or not since this question was posted more than one year ago. Also, not sure whether playing audio is a must in your app or not. If both answers are no, my recent investigation may help a bit.

Here are how I get my app getting accelerometer data at the background
1. Follow this tutorial http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/ to get the background location working.
2. Follow this tutorial http://jonathanhui.com/ios-motion to get the accelerometer working.

Then you can get an app collecting accelerometer data at the background. Hope this helps.

Comment: I just did a quick experiment. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/ plus http://jonathanhui.com/ios-motion work too. However, the problem is once another app took control of playing music. Then I can't get the accelerometer data. But should be sufficient for your purpose?